# Are Google Forms' JSON data missing Item Id's for sections (which is necessary for extracting skip logic)?

Tags: google-forms, google-forms-api

Google Form's data can be pulled by API. Using Python I pulled it like this:

```
from __future__ import print_function

from apiclient import discovery
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

import json

SCOPES = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/forms.body.readonly"
DISCOVERY_DOC = "https://forms.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1"

def get_google_form_data(form_id):
    creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('service.json', SCOPES)
    http_auth = creds.authorize(Http())
    service = discovery.build('forms', 'v1', http=http_auth, discoveryServiceUrl=DISCOVERY_DOC, static_discovery=False)

    result = service.forms().get(formId=form_id).execute()
    return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    form_id = 'xxx'
    json_data = get_google_form_data(form_id)

    with open("form_data.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(json_data, f, indent=4)
```

Respondents to the quiz may be shown different questions, depending on their answer. In the Form owner's web view of the Form, these the different sections are labeled consecutively ("Section 1", "Section 2", etc.) and they can associate values (a.k.a. answers) with "skip logic" using those section labels. For example the first answer may link to Section 10 and the second answer choice may link to Section 20.

In the JSON data, instead of those consecutive user-friendly labels, it calls it `goToSectionId` which is "Item ID of section header to go to". That would be simple and straightforward, but there's nothing in the API (that I can find) which can be used to find identify the corresponding section header or questions within the header. It has "questionID", which is also an Item ID, but those are not the same as the section ID.

I would assume I must've made a mistake, but if I search the raw JSON with any value from `goToSectionId`, in every case they only appear once, thus they provide no mapping. How can I extract the skip logic?

These are the API docs: https://developers.google.com/forms/api/reference/rest/v1/forms#QuestionItem

Comment: I would like to clarify something about your question, are referring about an identifier like "Title" "Description" on your JSON data and the response you are getting is not giving it?

Comment: @Babanana I have the Title and Description. However the questions are not always all asked and some may be asked in different orders. To know which question to ask, in which order (given a some initial answer choices) I must use the Item IDs in the goToSectionId field to find the next question, depending on the user's answer to a prior question. However, there are no section IDs to map against the goToSectionId values.

Comment: Thank you for your response. So to confirm this goToSectionId is being asked as a parameter on an endpoint? Do you mind sharing the endpoint here. Maybe this way we got a better grasp of your question.

Comment: I do apologize for the previous comment. I think the better question for you is are you using a library for your code.

Comment: @Babanana Just the libraries in the snippet above. I think the data is missing from the API response though, as I have searched the entire raw JSON responses with regex and found that the ID values in *goToSectionId* do not appear anywhere else.

Comment: I now understand your question thoroughly, I have read something from the end point that you are using "Option": {
      "id": "Option",
      "description": "An option for a Choice question.",
      "properties": {
        "goToSectionId": {
          "description": "Item ID of section header to go to.",
          "type": "string""  check the description about this it is looking for the item ID of the section you want to work with.

Comment: After all it is just the item ID, of the section from the response. Please let me know if this put you on the right track.

Comment: @Babanana The issue is that the API does not contain section ID's. So, let's say that the value of `goToSectionId` is `34ef253`. Since `34ef253` only appears once in the JSON data within `goToSectionId`, there's no way to know what section it pertains to.

Comment: This is just slightly weird as I am seeing all the item ID associated with each section as an object before the question starts and with an object element of pageBreakItem {}. Do : you think you can share the screenshot of what you are getting as a response in JSON.  By the way I doing a request "GET https://forms.googleapis.com/v1/forms/{formId}"

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem, have you found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I came across a very similar problem, i meaning the attribution of conditional logic to **ChoiceQuestion** type. However, having developed my project in **Java**, the solution I found is different, so please extract the "concept" despite the code which will probably not be useful to you.

Let's start with theory: we need to create a properly formatted JSON request to create a form. In this JSON request we can assign itemId properties chosen by us to the Items, rather than being satisfied with their automatic attribution.

i.e:

```
{
  "formId": null,
  "info":{
    "documentTitle":"Test1",
    "title":"Test 1"
  },
  "items":[{
    "itemId":"00000001",
    "questionItem": {
      "question":{
        "choiceQuestion":{
          "options":[{
            "value":"Option 1",
            "goToSectionId": "00000002"
          },
          {
            "value":"Option 2",
            "goToSectionId": "00000004"
          }],
          "type":"DROP_DOWN"
        },
        "questionId":"619ff865"}
    },
    "title":"Question 1"
  },
  {
    "description":"New Page descriptor",
    "itemId":"00000002",
    "pageBreakItem":{},
    "title":"ciao"
  },
    {
      "itemId":"00000003",
      "questionItem":{
        "question":{
          "choiceQuestion":{
            "options":[{
              "value":"Yes"
            },
              {
                "value":"No"
              }],
            "type":"RADIO"
          },
          "questionId":"73bcb98f"
        }},
      "title":"Question 2"
    },
    {
      "itemId":"00000004",
      "pageBreakItem":{
    },
      "title":"New Page descriptor"
    },
    {
      "itemId":"00000005",
      "questionItem":{
        "question":{
          "choiceQuestion":{
            "options":[{
              "value":"Yes"
            },
              {
                "value":"No"
              }],
            "type":"RADIO"
          },
          "questionId":"73bcb98f"
        }},
      "title":"Question 3"
    },],
  "responderUri": null,
  "revisionId": null
}
```

Please note that the JSON above consists of three questions and two page breaks. The answer to question 1 will activate the skip logic to **question 2 (item 00000003)** or **question 3 (item 00000005)**.

Please note that **pageBreakItems correspond to the options in question 1.**

In my case this was the difficult part. Having noted that the Google Form API and the related Java libraries use BatchRequest where each element is inserted sequentially, the insertion of question return an error because **there was no correspondence between the ids of the options and subsequent pageBreakitems** (*which had yet to be inserted*).

The solution in my case was to make 2 different requests:

1. The first to insert all elements and the PageBreakItems except the questions with a conditional logic (Question1)
2. The second to insert the question with a conditional logic, like the Question 1

As an example I attach the Java method I wrote:

```
 private void publishForm(Form form, CustomForm customForm) throws IOException {
        BatchUpdateFormRequest batchRequest = new BatchUpdateFormRequest();
        List<Request> requests = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Request> goToSectionIdTypeRequest = new ArrayList<>();
        Integer counter = 0;

        for(CustomItem item : customForm.getItems()){
            Request request = new Request();
            request.setCreateItem(new CreateItemRequest());
            request.getCreateItem().setLocation(new Location());
            request.getCreateItem().setItem(item.getItem());
            request.getCreateItem().getLocation().setIndex(counter);

            /*
            * If the element is a dropdown it can have also an goToSectionId parameter:
            * in this case, it must be pushed inside the form in a second time
            */
            if (item.getQuestionItem() != null) {
                if (item.getQuestionItem().getQuestion().getChoiceQuestion() != null) {
                    if (item.getQuestionItem().getQuestion().getChoiceQuestion().getType() != null) {
                        String choiceType = item.getQuestionItem().getQuestion().getChoiceQuestion().getType();
                        if (choiceType.equals(ChoiceType.DROPDOWN.label)) {
                            if (item.getQuestionItem().getQuestion().getChoiceQuestion().getOptions().get(1).getGoToSectionId() != null) {
                                goToSectionIdTypeRequest.add(request);
                                continue;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            requests.add(request);
            counter++;
        }
        batchRequest.setRequests(requests);
        this.formservice.forms().batchUpdate(form.getFormId(), batchRequest).setAccessToken(token).execute();

        batchRequest.setRequests(goToSectionIdTypeRequest);
        this.formservice.forms().batchUpdate(form.getFormId(), batchRequest).setAccessToken(token).execute();
```

It's not elegant but it works.

I remain at your disposal and I hope you can resolve your problem.

Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, Luca. Due to the amount of time that elapsed since asking the question, I'm no longer in a position to try to apply your solution. Therefore, I'm upvoting it without accepting it.

Comment: No problem bro.